# Selecting a subset of the population such that the distribution of a certain variable in the subset matches a reference distribution?

Tags: classification

I have a large population ($P$) of entries and I am given the distribution of a certain variable ($x_0$) for a specific subset ($S$) of the population. The subset $S$ is not a random sample and hence the distribution of $x_0$ for $S$ is not necessarily the same as that of $x_0$ for $P$.

I want to use all other available variables ($x_1...x_n$) to select another subset $S'$ from the set ($P-S$), such that the distribution of $x_0$ for $S'$ is the same as (or reasonably close to) that for $S$. That is, $S'$ mimics $S$ as far as the variable $x_0$ is concerned.

I am new to formal data science and I am not sure if machine learning is the best way to solve this problem. So far, my planned solution is to train a binary classifier on ($P-S$) that minimizes a loss that quantifies the difference in the target and obtained distributions' JS-divergences, the "obtained" being defined as entries with a predicted score $y_0 > 0.5$, or some other number, for instance. Then testing this model on separate test entries in ($P-S$) and applying a cut $y_0 > 0.5$ should give me $S'$.

Will this strategy work? Is there a more standard and elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand your method well, but I suspect that there is a major flaw in it: if the model classifies instances based on whether they satisfy the distribution condition, it means that the instances (for the classifier) represent distributions themselves (i.e. *subsets of elements*), not individual elements of the population.

In this option, the real problem is how to generate these subsets. It's possible but not trivial. I would suggest a genetic algorithm (not a binary classifier) which optimizes the JS divergence (for instance) from a population of subsets at every generation, starting from a population of random subsets.

Another option is to calculate the empirical probability distribution and resample $P-S$ by applying it:

- Define some precision parameter $\epsilon$ for the size of the intervals.
- Estimate the empirical probability distribution $p(x_0 \in I)$ on $S$ for every interval I with length $\epsilon$.
- Count the initial frequency $f(x_0 \in I)$ for every interval $I$ (same intervals) on $P-S$. Note that if there is any $I$ for which $f(x_0 \in I)=0$ and $p(x_0 \in I)>0$, it means that $\epsilon$ must be increased.
- We want to achieve the distribution $p(x_0 \in I)$ on $P-S$, so we have to calculate the new frequency $f'(x_0 \in I)$ such that:

  - $f'(x_0 \in I) \leq f(x_0 \in I)$ for every $I$, otherwise there are not enough available instances in $P-S$.
  - $f'(x_0 \in I) \approx n \times p(x_0 \in I)$ for some $n>0$ to satisfy the distribution ($n$ should be as high as possible).

So we have:

$$n \leq \frac{f(x_0 \in I)}{p(x_0 \in I)}$$ for every $I$.

We obtain the highest coefficient $n$ which satisfies this condition:

$$n=min_I\left( \frac{f(x_0 \in I)}{p(x_0 \in I)}\right)$$

Once $n$ is found we randomly pick $f'(x_0 \in I) \approx n \times p(x_0 \in I)$ instances in $P-S$ for every interval $I$.

Comment: I edited the equations, I had an error in the first version. Hopefully there's no error anymore ;)